# MySQL right join with tables with 100's of 1000's of rows

Tags: mysql, query-performance

The following join is taking far too long in MySQL, almost half a day and it’s still not finished:

```
INSERT INTO `aaaaa` 
SELECT * 
FROM `chosenLang` 
RIGHT JOIN `chosenLOCC_P` 
    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX
      (SUBSTRING_INDEX(`chosenLang`.`call`,'.',1),' ',1),'*',1) 
       LIKE concat(`chosenLOCC_P`.`code`,`chosenLOCC_P`.`reference`)
```

`chosenLang` has  413826 rows, 42 columns (38 of them longtext, 3 of them varchar, 1 of them int(11)). `call` is varchar.

`chosenLOCC_P` has 117077 rows, 23 columns (21 of them longtext, 2 of them int(10)).

What can I do to maximise the speed of this query?

Comment: You can create generated columns and indexes on them. But why do you need to run such query? Wouldn't be enough to select only ID columns from both tables?

Comment: Look like a pretty bad data design. You have to parse and prepare all the data before quering them.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Could you provide the DDL of the tables? `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G`.

Comment: With 38 `LONGTEXT` columns, the word "defund" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

- Make new columns to handle those clumsy expressions.
- Make them reasonably sized `VARCHARs`, not `LONGTEXT`.
- Write a 1-time script to populate those column(s).
- Change code so that future `INSERTs` (etc) maintain the columns.
- Add a suitable index so that the `JOIN` works efficiently.
- Use `JOIN` unless you really need `RIGHT JOIN`.  Are you currently hoping to get a lot of `NULL` columns.